# Javascript timer using setInterval() onclick and add duration, if a condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, dom, timer

```js
var score = 0,
  time = 10;

window.onload = function() {

  var input = document.getElementById("wordTyped");
  var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");

  input.addEventListener("click", timer, false);

  function timer() {
    var id = setInterval(countdown, 10);

    function countdown() {
      input.removeEventListener("click", timer, false);
      timeLeft.innerHTML = "Time left: " + (time - 0.01).toFixed(2) + "s";
      time = (time - 0.01).toFixed(2);

      if (time == 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
      }

      if (time == 7) {
        // The issue | it works if I assigned 10 to time but not for addition"
        time += 10;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="wordTyped" type="text" />
<div id="time">Time left: 10.00s</div>
```

The code I wrote above is fairly straight forward but its not working the way I'm expecting it to work.

If input is clicked, start timer and *if* `time == 7` (for testing sake, I give the condition for time equals 7), add 10 to time but it doesn't add and keeps on decrementing  until it reach zero where the `setInterval` is cleared

Comment: well toFixed() makes it a string.....

Comment: Since you're setting `time` to a string, `time += 10` does string concatenation, so it changes it from `"7.00"` to `"7.0010"`.

Comment: What `@epascarello` said.... and... You will want to multiply your decimals by `Math.pow(10, 17)` then divide by the same if doing addition or subtraction in JavaScript. This way the numbers are not decimals... then you change them back to decimals. JavaScript has issues with decimal addition and subtraction.

Comment: Ah I see..didn't know toFixed changes it to string, I was going for the `time` to be displayed in 2 decimal places as a number value

@PHPglue oh that seems complicated for a simple task

Comment: That's JavaScript for you. They make decimal Math addition and subtraction a complicated task. `var mp = Math.pow(10, 17);
console.log(1.1+1.3); console.log((1.1*mp+1.3*mp)/mp);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `toFixed()` when assigning to `time`. That returns a string, not a number, so `time += 10` performs string concatenation, not addition. Use it only when displaying the time, not storing the time variable in the code.

However, if you keep `time` as a number, floating point inaccuracies may result in `time == 7` never being true. You should test for it being close to `7`:

```
if (Math.abs(time - 7) < 0.005)
```

Comment: When I did `console.log(time)` where time _is_ a number, it print `7` at some point, which means that time _is_ equal to seven at that instance hence should run the if statement, right? Or should I take precaution because I'm dealing with floating point?

Comment: You should take precaution. The error might be a very small fraction, which might not be shown in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello, thanks for clarifying, wish I can upvote your comment.

If `toFixed()` set it into a string, then all that needs to be done is to revert it back into a number type.

So I change

`time = (time - 0.01).toFixed(2);`

into

`time = 1 * (time - 0.01).toFixed(2);`